# Java custom component

Tags: java, user-interface, components, game-engine

I am trying  to develop a small 2d game in java. All objects in my code extend Rectangle in order to avoid re-writing geometry code about intersections, moving etc. My next issue is drawing all my objects. At the moment I designed a Renderer class that clears the background and redraws all the objects. On the other side, I observed that this is done automatically for java Components that are added to a panel (once a component is added, whenever I modify it's position the component is updating by its own).
My next thought was to extend my object class with Component, but I can't do that, because I already extended it with Rectangle.
How should I work this around?

I hope I made myself clear enough :)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with a delegation pattern : 
Use an interface IRectangle, in wich you write all the methods that your Rectangle class have. In such case, Rectangle and your Component class have to implements IRectangle.

In rectangle class you have your implementation, in your component class, you create an instance of Rectangle or give it to your constructor, and in all methods you have to write beacause of the interface, you can call the instance off Rectangle.

Exemple :

```
public interface IRectangle{
   public int getWidth();
   ...
}
public class Rectangle implements IRectangle{
   ...
   public int getWidth(){
       return this.width;
   }
}
public class CustomComponent extends Component implements IRectangle{
   private Rectangle rect;
   public CustomComponent(Rectangle rect){
        this.rect = rect;
   }
   ...
   public int getWidth(){
       return this.rect.getWidth();
   }
}
```

Sorry for my poor english skills, I hope you can understand what I mean ^^'